# Loading only a part of the data in a HDF5 file into memory with Python

Tags: python, hdf5, h5py, pytables

To load data in a HDF5 file into memory, one can use pandas.read_hdf function with a list of columns to load. However, this way an entire table is loaded into memory, and then some columns are dropped. Thus the initial memory usage is much larger than the actual size of the data.

Is there a way to load only the columns of interest?

Comment: Are you willing to use something besides pandas? If so, you could use pytables or h5py to slice a numpy array. I use both, and prefer pytables. It has better query and search functionality. h5py is more numpy-like, and also popular.

Comment: @kcw78 I could use h5py or pytables. Would one of these provide a function to access only a part of HDF file, without loading all data in it at any moment?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nownuri, Both offer methods to read part of the file.
With `pytables`, there are several methods to read a table into a numpy array. These include:

- `table.read()` lets you slice the data,
- `table.read_coordinates()` reads a set [noconsecutive] coordinates
  (aka rows),
- `table.read_where()` read a set of based on a search condition

All support an optional `field=''` parameter to read a single column of data based on the field name (like a numpy recarry).
For complete details, read the Pytables documentation.
You can find it here: [PyTables User Guide](https://www.pytables.org/usersguide/index.html)

`h5py` has similar (but different) methods based on numpy array slicing conventions. For h5py details, access the documentation here: [H5py Documentation](http://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/index.html)

Below are very simple (self-contained) examples for each. I create the data in write mode, then reopen the file in read mode. You probably only need the second half of each example (how to read the data). Also HDF5 files are independent of creation method: you could read either HDF5 file with h5py or pytables (independent of how they were created).

**Pytables method:**
This method shows 2 different ways to access a table w/ pytables. The first uses 'Natural Naming' to get h5_i_arr, and the second uses the `get_node()` method to read `h5_x_arr`.

```
import tables as tb
import numpy as np

with tb.File('SO_57342918_tb.h5','w') as h5f:

    i_arr=np.arange(10)
    x_arr=np.arange(10.0)

    my_dt = np.dtype([ ('i_arr', int), ('x_arr', float) ] )
    table_arr = np.recarray( (10,), dtype=my_dt )
    table_arr['i_arr'] = i_arr
    table_arr['x_arr'] = x_arr

    my_ds = h5f.create_table('/','ds1',obj=table_arr)

# read 1 column using field= parameter:   
with tb.File('SO_57342918_tb.h5','r') as h5f:

    h5_i_arr = h5f.root.ds1.read(field='i_arr')
    h5_x_arr = h5f.get_node('/ds1').read(field='x_arr')
    print (h5_i_arr)
    print (h5_x_arr)
```

**h5py method:**

```
import h5py
import numpy as np

with h5py.File('SO_57342918_h5py.h5','w') as h5f:

    i_arr=np.arange(10)
    x_arr=np.arange(10.0)

    my_dt = np.dtype([ ('i_arr', int), ('x_arr', float) ] )
    table_arr = np.recarray( (10,), dtype=my_dt )
    table_arr['i_arr'] = i_arr
    table_arr['x_arr'] = x_arr

    my_ds = h5f.create_dataset('/ds1',data=table_arr)

# read 1 column using numpy slicing: 
with h5py.File('SO_57342918_h5py.h5','r') as h5f:

    h5_i_arr = h5f['ds1'][:,'i_arr']
    h5_x_arr = h5f['ds1'][:,'x_arr']
    print (h5_i_arr)
    print (h5_x_arr)
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! It seems the methods are useful when the HDF file contains numpy arrays. If the file contains a pandas dataframe, is it still possible to read a subset of the columns of the dataframe?

Comment: Nownuri I am not familiar with Pandas dataframes. If the file is written in HDF5 format, you should be able to read and extract the data with `pytables` or `h5py`. The trick is understanding the schema. HDF5 uses a group/dataset layout, where groups are like folders and datasets are files. The data can be (2D) tables or various Array formats. You can extract any table or array data to a numpy array. HDF Group has a utility to view HDF5 data.It's called **HDFView**. This is the fastest way to see the schema. Or, you can run h5dump or ptdump.

Comment: @kcw78: Awesome! Your answer is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!