# read row for given id from pickle file without loading all data

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with 2 columns (ID, Contents) which I am saving in `pickle` format. Say for example, I have 10 rows(ie 0 to 9 ID). I am trying to load a single row by passing `ID` (valid ID between 0-9) from the **pickle file without loading the entire file**.

```
import pandas as pd
import pickle

id = 2
path = "contents.pickle"

# dummy data
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "ID": [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
    "Contents": [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
})

print(f"{df=}")

df.to_pickle(path=path)

df = pd.read_pickle(filepath_or_buffer=path)

with open(path, "rb") as handle:
    df = pickle.load(handle)
```

The above both are reading all the data in one go. I am not getting where I should pass the `ID` to load that row only. If not possible with `dataframe`, I tried with simple `list` containing data saved in pickle file using reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37954324/how-to-load-one-line-at-a-time-from-a-pickle-file) but failed.

```
data = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

with open(path, "wb") as handle:
    pickle.dump(data, handle)

file = open(file=path)

file.seek(id)

row = pickle.load(file)

print(f"{row=}")
```

Comment: Just to be clear, your objective is to pick out a row by id from within the picked result somehow and just load it, not the entire pickled dataframe/list then filter.

Comment: @JonSG, Yes without loading entire dataframe or list. Also, df.index and ID are same. I get an `id` from frontend and want to load that index(or ID) which will return corresponding single row.

Comment: I think you might look into fixed record lengths that you could `seek()` into.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately I think `pickle` is not the right tool to do that (but maybe I'm wrong). Try a column-oriented data file format like `parquet` and [`pd.read_parquet`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_parquet.html):

```
df.to_parquet('results.parquet')

row = pd.read_parquet('results.parquet', filters=[('ID', '=', 9)])
```

Output:

```
>>> row
   ID  Contents
0   9         9
```

**Update**

With `pyarrow` and [`ParquetDataset`](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.parquet.ParquetDataset.html)

```
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

ds = pq.ParquetDataset('results.parquet', filters=[('ID', '=', 9)])
```

Output:

```
>>> ds.read()  # read to get the row without load the entire file
pyarrow.Table
ID: int64
Contents: int64
----
ID: [[9]]
Contents: [[9]]
```

Comment: Hi Corralien, Sorry to bother you. Currently I am using second solution i.e.  using `pyarrow and ParquetDataset` which does not load entire file in memory and just return the given `id` as you mentioned. I want to know the first solution i.e. using `pandas.read_parquet with filters argument` holds true i.e. it also does not load entire file in memory and just return the given `id` or is it just restricted to `pyarrow` and not to `pandas`?

Comment: Both solutions have the same behavior if you use filters. `read_parquet` is probably a convenient function to hide `pyarrow`.

Comment: Hi Corralien, Thanks. Yes, then its better to use `pandas read_parquet`.

Answer (score 1):

H5Py allows to access specific data efficiently **without loading the entire dataset into memory**

**Sample Code:**

```
import h5py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "ID": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
    "Contents": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
})

with h5py.File('data.h5', 'w') as h5file:
    h5file.create_dataset('ID', data=df['ID'].values)
    h5file.create_dataset('Contents', data=df['Contents'].values)

with h5py.File('data.h5', 'r') as h5file:
    id_to_load = 2

    # column base loading
    id_dataset = h5file['ID'][:]
    contents_dataset = h5file['Contents'][:]

    index = (id_dataset == id_to_load) # find the index where 'ID' 
    loaded_row = pd.DataFrame({
        "ID": id_dataset[index],
        "Contents": contents_dataset[index]
    })

print(f"{id_to_load}:\n{loaded_row}")
```

**Output:**

```
   ID  Contents
2   2         2
```

**Inspired from:** [Loading only a part of the data in a HDF5 file into memory with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57342918/loading-only-a-part-of-the-data-in-a-hdf5-file-into-memory-with-python)

Comment: Hi Omer, Thanks. I have updated the title. I guess `read_pickle` will load all data.

Comment: @winter HDF5 may help u without loading the entire data into memory

Answer (score 1):

Is there a particular reason you are saving as a pickle file? You might be better off just storing as a CSV and just using regular `pd.read_csv` with the `skiprows` argument:

```
df = pd.read_csv('test_file.csv', skiprows = lambda x: x != 9)
```

as opposed to using a pickle file which does not easily allow incremental access.

Answer (score 1):

> to load a single row by passing ID (valid ID between 0-9) from the
> pickle file without loading the entire file.

`pickle` doesn't provide such functionality.
Instead, use [Parquet](https://parquet.apache.org/docs/overview/motivation/) storage format, which is efficient and provides flexible filtering.
Write a df into a parquet file with [`df.to_parquet`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_parquet.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_parquet). (You might need to install `pyarrow` or `fastparquet` extentions)

Then, use [`pd.read_parquet`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_parquet.html#pandas.read_parquet) with custom filters:

```
path = "df.parquet"

# dummy data
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "ID": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
    "Contents": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
})

df.to_parquet(path, engine='pyarrow')
row = pd.read_parquet(path, filters=[('ID', '=', 1)], engine='pyarrow')

print(row)
```

---

```
   ID  Contents
0   1         1
```

Comment: It's like my answer ;-)

Comment: @Corralien, mine provides more explanation/nuances and references